# Linq statement to select strings containing all of the letters

Tags: c#, string, linq

I have a list of strings, I would like to select all of those that contains some letters (all of the letters in any position)
I tried the following code

```
selWords = wordlist.Where(x.IndexOfAny("aeo".ToCharArray()) != -1).ToList();
```

It gives me all the words which contain any of `a`,`e`,`o` letters but I need those which contains all of these letters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string test1 = "sdfasdosdfe";
string test2 = "sdfasdasodfeasdfasd";
string test3 = "sdfsdfsdfsdfds";
string searchString = "aeo";

List<string> wordList = new List<string>() { test1, test2, test3 };
IEnumerable<string> resultList = 
     wordList.Where(q => searchString.ToCharArray().All(p => q.Contains(p)));
```

Comment: string implements `IEnumerable<char>`, so we don't need to convert to `char[]` explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are many solutions, here's the one that I find most elegant:

```
var matches = wordlist.Where(w => "aeo".All(l => w.Contains(l)));
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use Linq for that

```
var result = from word in wordlist
where word .Contains("a") && word .Contains("e") && word .Contains("o")
select word;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do

```
selWords = wordlist.Where(x => x.IndexOfAny("a".ToCharArray()) != -1
                               &&
                               x.IndexOfAny("e".ToCharArray()) != -1
                               &&
                               x.IndexOfAny("o".ToCharArray()) != -1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to same thing but the data source was from MySql database and this fix it

```
`var result= _context.dataSource.AsEnumerable().Where(w => searchLetters.Any(x => y.LastName.Contains(x)));`
```